# Authenticate client routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I develop an application with React, Node.js and JSON Web Token.
I want to secure client routes.
I don't want to give access to client routes if not authenticated, also in case the user changes the client by himself.

For example:

Most posts I saw used something like this:

```
 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    Auth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to='/login' />
  )} />
)
```

It's clear that `Auth.isAuthenticated` can be changed by any client by doing: 
`Auth.isAuthenticated = true`
or any other syntax.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Do redirect with `Auth.isAuthenticated`. Don't worry about that it's not 100% secure, it fine. But you need to secure you backend endpoints to properly authenticate session.